# How to generate error on Webview?

Tags: android, webview

I developed a website for my entreprisee and I work almost exclusively with PHP

So the Java language (and android studio) is a really new for me

Despite this I have to create an APK to use the website (in order to block the android home on this site)

**I would like to know how to generate errors in order to test this function**

```
public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView webView;

    SwipeRefreshLayout swipe;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.awv_progressBar);
        swipe = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe);
        LoadWeb();

        progressBar.setMax(100);
        progressBar.setProgress(1);


        swipe = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe);
        swipe.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                webView.reload();
            }
        });


        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                progressBar.setProgress(progress);
            }
        });


        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");
            }

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                //Don't show ProgressBar
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                //Hide the SwipeRefreshLayout
                swipe.setRefreshing(false);
            }

        });

    }

    public void LoadWeb() {

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("mysite.com");
        swipe.setRefreshing(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            finish();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: From the documentation: "Report web resource loading error to the host application. These errors usually indicate inability to connect to the server."

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this could be by adding a proxy(using app like fiddler) which returns custom error code as per your wish for all requests from your device.
In case you do not need specific error codes, just use a random system wide wifi proxy which actually does not exist. In this case, device will try sending data to this proxy but won't find it and you will get a callback in onReceivedError.